# C# merge one directory with another

Tags: c#, directory

I have an autoupdater C# program. It will download a rar file that holds the changed or new files for the update to some software. The rar file has it's structure just like the base directory of the software but only contains changed or new files/folders. Is there an easy way to "merge" these files/folders to the destination directory so in that if the file/folder exists already it'll be replaced and if not it'll be added or do I have to manually walk through each file/folder and do this myself? Just hoping there is a nice little merge function that .NET has :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[**DirectoryInfo Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx)

> The following example demonstrates how to copy a directory and its contents.
>
> ```
> public static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
> {
>     if (source.FullName.ToLower() == target.FullName.ToLower())
>     {
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // Check if the target directory exists, if not, create it.
>     if (Directory.Exists(target.FullName) == false)
>     {
>         Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
>     }
>
>     // Copy each file into it's new directory.
>     foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine(@"Copying {0}\{1}", target.FullName, fi.Name);
>         fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
>     }
>
>     // Copy each subdirectory using recursion.
>     foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
>     {
>         DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir =
>             target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
>         CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Wondering why your post is not shown to me when i write one myself??

Comment: @FelixK. I posted an answer, then I thought it wasn't the right one, deleted it, edited while it was deleted and undeleted. A common practice, frankly.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to use the [FileSystem.MoveDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128003.aspx) method. Make sure you add a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
...
// Merge D:\SourceDir with D:\DestDir:
FileSystem.MoveDirectory("D:\\SourceDir", "D:\\DestDir", true /* Overwrite */);
```

Comment: Question is to merge source directory with destination directory, will MoveDirectory work in this case? I believe MoveDirectory tends to create a new directory on destination and will raise an error "Cannot create a file when that file already exists" if directory already exists.

Comment: Why believe if you could try? It will merge the directories, so you will end up with a single DestDir with all the contents combined.