# Moving Folder to same named Folder

Tags: c#, io, filesystems

I have some folder which i check while my programm is running.
I remove the unnecessary folders and return the checked folders to a other directory.

My Problem is that I always get an Exception. And i really don't know why.
btw:  current and new tables have the same names
:[image: My Exception]
Translation because its in german: a data can't be created because it already exists.
My Code:

```
public void CreateCheckedStructure() { 

        List<string> checkedDirNew = Program.RemoveTempFolders(GetAllFromDir(Settings.Default.NewFolder));
        List<string> checkedDirCurrent = Program.RemoveTempFolders(GetAllFromDir(Settings.Default.CurrentFolder));

        foreach(string checkedNew in checkedDirNew){

            DirectoryInfo dirInfoNew = new DirectoryInfo(checkedNew);
            foreach (string checkedCurrent in checkedDirCurrent) {
                DirectoryInfo dirInfoCurrent = new DirectoryInfo(checkedCurrent);
                if(dirInfoNew.Name.Equals(dirInfoCurrent.Name)){
                    string checkedFoldersPath = Settings.Default.CheckedTables + "\\" + dirInfoCurrent.Name;
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(checkedFoldersPath);
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(checkedFoldersPath+"\\New");
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(checkedFoldersPath + "\\Current");
                    dirInfoCurrent.MoveTo(checkedFoldersPath + "\\Current");
                    dirInfoNew.MoveTo(checkedFoldersPath + "\\New");
                    break;
                }
            }        
        }

    }
```

Comment: I edited my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating `checkedFoldersPath+"\\New"`, and then trying to copy another folder on top of it. The error occurs because it already exists. If you're trying to merge the two folders, you will have to move all the subfiles and subdirectories (recursively) to the new folder, then delete the original folder.

See this answer: [C# merge one directory with another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9053614/2644015)